# Why Can't I Combine CSS-Transform with CSS Calc?

Tags: sass

```
transform-origin: calc(100% - (44px / 2)) 44px / 2;
```

It seems to invalidate things and just makes it regress to default transform-origin: center.

The point is that I need to 'responsively' calculate the x-offset of transform-origin somehow.

Comment: The second calculation is missing the `calc` function.

Comment: You know what? This is actually a bad question. I meant to ask it in reference to working with Sass variables, but I substituted the literal values, so it actually looks really weird and is poorly asked.

Answer (score 1):

If the last `44px / 2` wasn't a typo, delete that.  That is outside the `calc()`.  If it is a typo, can you give us some more code?  Some html would be nice.

Heres a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r0hp81ky/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what ended up working:

```
transform-origin: calc(100% - #{$hit-area} / 2) ($hit-area / 2);
```